# Unrecognized option 'filter_complex'

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg version 0.10.15. When I try to run this command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i wlogo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:y=(main_h-overlay_h)-10" test123.mp4
```

It gives me error:

```
Unrecognized option 'filter_complex'
Failed to set value 'overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)-10:y=(main_h-overlay_h)-10' for option 'filter_complex'
```

Comment: The current release version is 3.0. Yours is very old.

Comment: yes and my os is centos .but i found solution we use -vf for that

/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i new1.mp4  -vf "movie=wlogo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" -strict experimental  output.mp4